# NSUserDefaults Question (how do i open a different viewController when needed while starting the app)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm trying to start a different ViewController when a BOOL in NSUserDefaults isn't set..
When the "RegistreerView" is loaded the screen stays white? What do i do wrong? How can i start a different ViewController when starting my application.

I use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL *geregistreerd = [defaults objectForKey:@"geregistreerd"];
if(geregistreerd){
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
} else {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.registreerView;
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you instantiating the `reistreerView` prior to this code?

Comment: sorry i'm new to xcode, so im not really sure what u mean. In the delegate header file ive set it (also as property). And i did @synthesize. Just like a standard Delegate class init his viewController when i create a new project..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you may not be instantiating your nib, as I don't see anywhere in this method that creates it above.  If not, you could try the following:

```
SomeView *yourView = [[SomeView alloc] initWithName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = yourView;
[yourView release];
```

Replacing `SomeView` and `YourViewController` with the appropriate names.

Answer (score 1):

The way you retrieve the `BOOL` in `NSUserDefaults` isn't correct. You should use `-(BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)defaultName;`. Also you declared `geregistreerd` as a pointer to a `BOOL` (`BOOL *`), where you should declare a `BOOL`, so this could result in undefined behaviour.
In order to display the view controller you want, make sure they are correctly init/alloced, or properly connected to your user interface in NIB.

Answer (score 0):

`objectForKey` returns a string value stored in the plist. You need to convert the string to a boolean.

```
BOOL *geregistreerd = [[defaults objectForKey:@"geregistreerd"] boolValue];
```

Comment: ok thnx, but that dousnt resolve my problem, also when delete the whole if/else statement and do self.window.rootViewController = self.registreerView; the screen stays white

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, u have not initialized the `registreerView` variable. Actually the viewController in the application delegate is initialized thru nib file. So, initialize the `registreerView` variable.

The else part should be :

```
else {
    RegistreerView *registreerView = [[RegistreerView alloc] initWibNibname:@"" bundle:nil];
    self.registreerView = registreerView;
    [registreerView release];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.registreerView;
}
```

Give the appropriate nib name. Else give it as nil.